# what's wrong with my lookAt and move forward code?

Tags: libgdx, rotation, movement

so am still in the process of getting familiar with libGdx and one of the fun things i love to do is to make basics method for reusability on future projects, and for now am stacked on getting a Sprite rotate toward target (vector2) and then move forward based on that rotation 
the code am using is this :

```
    // set angle
   public void lookAt(Vector2 target) {

      float angle = (float) Math.atan2(target.y - this.position.y, target.x
            - this.position.x);
      angle = (float) (angle * (180 / Math.PI));

      setAngle(angle);

   }

   // move forward
   public void moveForward() {
      this.position.x += Math.cos(getAngle())*this.speed;
      this.position.y += Math.sin(getAngle())*this.speed;
   }
```

and this is my render method  :

```
    @Override
   public void render(float delta) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.0f, 1);
      Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      // groupUpdate();

      Vector3 mousePos = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
      camera.unproject(mousePos);
      ball.lookAt(new Vector2(mousePos.x, mousePos.y));
      //

      if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
         ball.moveForward();
      }

      batch.begin();
      batch.draw(ball.getSprite(), ball.getPos().x, ball.getPos().y, ball
            .getSprite().getOriginX(), ball.getSprite().getOriginY(), ball
            .getSprite().getWidth(), ball.getSprite().getHeight(), .5f,
            .5f, ball.getAngle());
      batch.end();
   }
```

the goal is to make the ball always look at the mouse cursor, and then move forward when i click, am also using this camera :

```
// create the camera and the SpriteBatch
  camera = new OrthographicCamera();
  camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
```

aaaand the result was so creepy lol 
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Reminds me of the way people walk in [South Park](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Park)... maybe this should be a feature? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am really impressed by the build-in method of libGdx, this is what am looking for :

```
// set angle
public void lookAt(Vector2 target) {

    setAngle(target.sub(position).angle());

}

// move forward
public void moveForward() {

    position.add(new Vector2(speed, 0).rotate(getAngle()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This part looks suspect to me:

```
  public void moveForward() {
      this.position.x += Math.cos(getAngle())*this.speed;
      this.position.y += Math.sin(getAngle())*this.speed;
   }
```

I'd do that sort of thing using vector maths which is usually faster, something like this (pseudocode):

```
  public void moveForward() {
     Vector2 directionToMouse = mousePosition - this.position;
     directionToMouse.Normalize();
     this.position += directionToMouse * speed;
   }
```

Comment: i don't understand how the cameraPosition can be helpful here since it's always going to be (0;0)

Comment: You're right sorry, I meant mousePosition - I'll update.

Comment: this isn't what am looking for, i don't want to move toward the mouse, i want to look to the mouse, but move forward based on that rotation

Comment: You could store the normalized directionToMouse instead of the angle to achieve the same thing.